# C# PictureBox on top of another PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I want the `pbGrade` to be on top of `pbItemtype` (pb = picture box)

```
 pbItemtype.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

 // Change parent for overlay PictureBox...
 pbItemtype.Parent = pbGrade;
```

I already tried this but then the pbItemtype is not even appearing, also the 2 picture boxes change images (pbItemtype and pbGrade)

[image]

Comment: You cannot easily do that.

Comment: well I know that much :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well actually you can do that easily and **in fact you already did**.

The code works **but** you also need to correct the `Location` as the nested PB will keep it previous one and thus will probably be off to the bottom right, probably leaving the visible size of the new `Parent`.... :

```
pbItemtype.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

// Change parent for overlay PictureBox...
pbItemtype.Parent = pbGrade;
// Move it to the top left of the parent:
pbItemtype.Location = Point.Empty;  // or some other position..
```

Transparency works well when **nesting** controls. It doesn't work when **overlapping** them, though !

(Of course the code we see will **not** exchange the images!)

Comment: working nicely had to play a bit with pb order but yeah :P

Answer (score 3):

Best approach is to construct the image with overlays off-line in a Bitmap object, then assign that constructed image to the PictureBox for display.

For example like this:

```
int width = 100;
int height = 100;
Image image = new Bitmap(width, height);

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    graphics.DrawImage(MyApplication.Properties.Resources.ImageItemX, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
    graphics.DrawImage(MyApplication.Properties.Resources.ImageGradeZ, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
}

myPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
myPictureBox.Image = image;
```

This assumes that `ImageItemX` and `ImageGradeZ` are images with a transparent background (for example pngs) imported as project resources under these names.

---

For example given these resources

[image: Images defined in resources in project]

the code will produce this:

[image: Form showing combined images in PictureBox]

Comment: Actually OP asks for 'nothing more' than looking through the PBox onto the one below. No problem, as long as no controls are suposed to __overlap__.. - Still: Drawing stuff on the fly is also and often a good option..

Comment: yeah true TaW what I want is to look thought the other picrure box to another picture box

Answer (score 0):

In General, if you have two picture boxes and you want one of them to overlap the other is as simple as making the overlapped picture be generated before the overlapping picture:

You can alter the order of these statements on the Form.Designer.cs file.

Change this:

```
this.Add(this.main_image);
this.Add(this.background_image);
```

To this:

```
this.Add(this.background_image);
this.Add(this.main_image);
```